# NetworkError on Firefox when aborting request before completion

Tags: javascript, firefox, fetch, abort

I'm doing something like:

```
fetch(url, ...)
.then(...)
.catch(e => {
  // Handle error here
});
```

On Firefox, however, whenever I navigate to a another page too quickly (ie. without all requests finishing), it will throw an error, which will trigger error handling in the UI

TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource"

I've found the discussion around this topic here, but it falls short of providing a workaround for the time being.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1280189

Wondering if there is any way to detect an abort by the browser, and handle it gracefully.

I've seen similar questions, but all those seem to be related with CORS, and are a different problem that this one.

Edit: reproduction in the before mentioned ticket:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
console.log("navigating away")

};
console.log("starting")
fetch("https://jsfiddle.net/").then(x => {
  console.log("fetched")
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("caught", e)
})
window.location = "https://jsfiddle.net/";
```

Returns:

```
caught TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
```

Comment: You can now use the AbortController method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController - This acts very similarly to axios' .cancel() method. This article goes into details about AbortController usage with fetch - https://itnext.io/how-you-can-abort-fetch-request-on-a-flight-830a639b9b92

Comment: @InchHigh I have tried that approach, but Firefox does not raise an AbortError when I navigate away. 

In demos where abort controller is explicitly called everything works, so it's either that firefox actually does not use the abort controller, or something else. 

Is the only alternative a refactor that calls the AbortController on every navigate away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some back and forth I managed to implement Inch High abort controller approach - developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController